# How many subsets does $A$ have that no two elements have sum $7$?

Tags: combinatorics

$A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.
If we omit those subsets of $A$ that have at least one of $(1,6)$ or $(2,5)$ or $(3,4)$ from all the subsets, then we'll get the answer. Can anyone tell how? 
I've tried different ways, but no success. Its a multiple choice question and the choices are:

a) $32$
b) $14$
c) $108$
d) $84$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the number of subsets containing at least $\color\red0$ out of $3$ pairs: $\binom{3}{\color\red0}\cdot2^{9-2\cdot\color\red0}=512$
- Exclude the number of subsets containing at least $\color\red1$ out of $3$ pairs: $\binom{3}{\color\red1}\cdot2^{9-2\cdot\color\red1}=384$
- Include the number of subsets containing at least $\color\red2$ out of $3$ pairs: $\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot2^{9-2\cdot\color\red2}=96$
- Exclude the number of subsets containing at least $\color\red3$ out of $3$ pairs: $\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot2^{9-2\cdot\color\red3}=8$

Hence the total number of subsets is $512-384+96-8=216$.

Answer (score 6):

$A=\{1,6\}\cup\{2,5\}\cup\{3,4\}\cup\{7\}\cup\{8\}\cup\{9\}$.  The number of choices for subsets of $A$ satisfying the given constraint (no two elements sum to $7$) is $(2^2-1)^3\cdot2^3=216$.

This is not one of the choices, so there is something wrong in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Perhaps the problem meant to exclude $7$ from all subsets, which would make the answer $108$.